# 2D Array: Retrieve the "Left" Item

Tags: java, array

I am creating a game that contains a Board and Pieces. The Board is basically a 2D array of Pieces. [Think smaller chess board]

One of the things that I want to accomplish is to be able to retrieve the left piece of a given.. (Also want to be able to retrieve the right, up, and down).

The easiest way to achieve this is to simply do something like:

```
board[i-1][j] //which will give me the piece that's to the left of board[i][j]
```

The problem with just doing this is that this can get ugly and there is no error checking (array out of range).

I have a feeling that there may be a better data structure to use than a 2D array.

Also, I have two implementations that work, but neither really seem like a good idea

I have the following (untested) Java classes, which is a small scale of my application:

the class Board:

```
public class Board 
{
protected Piece[][] board;

public Board()
{
    board = new Piece[7][7];
    int ctr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = new Piece(i, j, ctr++);
        }
    }
}

public Piece PieceAt(int i, int j)
{
    return board[i][j];
}

public Piece LeftOf(Piece p)
{
    return PieceAt(p.verticalIndex, p.horizontalIndex - 1);
}
}
```

And the Piece class

```
public class Piece 
{
    int verticalIndex;
    int horizontalIndex;
    int value;

    public Piece(int i, int j, int value)
    {
        this.horizontalIndex = i;
        this.verticalIndex = j;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Piece GetLeftPiece(Board b)
    {       
        return (this.horizontalIndex == 0 ? null : b.PieceAt(this.horizontalIndex, this.verticalIndex - 1));
    }
}
```

The first implementation sits in `Board.java`. The problem with this is that If I want to call it, it's a big ugly: `b.LeftOf(b.PieceAt(3,3))` where b is of  type Board.

The second implementation seems like a better idea, however since the Pieces no nothing about each other, I have to include board in the method signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first location of the `leftOf` method is the way to go. Putting it in `Piece` isn't very [cohesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29). The latter would be just as ugly or uglier (`b.pieceAt(3,3).getLeftPiece(b)`). The syntax `board.leftOf(b.pieceAt(3,3))`, [read aloud,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_ducking) communicates roughly your intent but might read better as `board.getPieceLeftOf(b.pieceAt(3,3))`. Further, the best way is to remove the middle man and change the interface:

```
public Piece getPieceLeftOf(int x, int y) {
    int leftLocation = x - 1;
    // Validate that location
    return pieceAt(leftLocation, y);
}

//  ...later
board.getPieceLeftOf(3, 3);
```

Some style notes/thoughts:

- Since this is written in Java, you should be following the [standard naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). camelCase for method names
- You have a lot of package and package-private fields, it's a better practice to make them private and then expose the ones that actually need to be exposed outside of the class. ([Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html) Item 13).
- If there is no error checking for the `pieceAt` or `leftOf` methods then add it and communicate through javadocs what happens if there is no left piece, a request is made out of bounds, etc. Those are both implemenation and game-type rules that need to be considered.
- It seems like a simple 2D array is fine for this application. That is a pretty common structure for 2D chess/checkers type games (quick access, easy mental model, etc).